# How to retrieve a model and it's relationship as a single Array or Object | Eloquent, Eloquent: Relationships

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

i have 3 tables with one-to-one relationship. The phone table has one to one relationship with Model table and Model table has a one to one relationship with Manufacturer table.

```
phone_table
    id
    imei
    image
    model_id

model_table
    id
    name
    image
    manufracturer_id

manufracturer_table
    id
    name
    logo
```

how to get a result like this :-

```
App\Phone{
    imei : "356554512522148",
    model : "Galaxy S-10",
    manufracturer : "Samsung",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  would never throw it into the same array / object, i would firstly do that on transformation. If you use default Laravel transformation you can use getters for it. Simple example on how  to access these fields into the same context would be.

```
$phone = Phone::with('model.manufactor')->find(1);
```

With secures the queries are optimal for accessing it. How to get data into same layer.

```
[
    'imei' => $phone->imei,
    'model' => $phone->model->name,
    'manufactor' => $phone->model->manufactor->name,
]
```

For this to work, you need relations in your model too.

`Phone.php`

```
public function model()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Model::class);
}
```

`Model.php`

```
public function manufactor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Manufactor::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join them:

```php
\App\Phone::leftjoin('model_table AS mo', 'mo.id', '=','phone_table.model_id')
          ->leftjoin('manufracturer_table AS ma', 'ma.id', '='. 'mo.manufracturer_id')
          ->selectRaw('phone_table.imei, mo.name AS model, ma.name AS manufracturer')
          ->first()
```

And sometimes you need to think about why you want to split table to one-to-one relationship.

Is there a table not usually be used, or one of them need to be connected  by another tables. is this just for saving space or reduce IO cost.

If there are not any other reason and you always need to get these tables' information, maybe you can merge to one table.

Comment: in general joining in Laravel is an anti pattern as it can have side effects, like overwriting you id's, this is thought of. But i would only use this as a last result.

Comment: @mrhn Honestly, this side effect can be avoid by select. And use `select()` to limit fields' count is better than take all fields out.

Comment: @mrhn and true. use general joining in Laravel  looks not elegant.